# Is "let x = ~10;" obsolete in Rust?

Tags: rust

I read this [tutorial](http://aml3.github.io/RustTutorial/html/02.html#Owned_Boxes) and tried the following Rust code:

```
fn main() {
    let x = ~10;
    println!("{:d}", *x);
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
rustc 1.16.0 (30cf806ef 2017-03-10)
error: expected expression, found `~`
 --> <anon>:2:13
  |
2 |     let x = ~10;
  |             ^

error: unknown format trait `d`
 --> <anon>:3:22
  |
3 |     println!("{:d}", *x);
  |                      ^^
```

Is `let x = ~10;` obsolete already?

Comment: Yes. To be fair, this was removed a while ago: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/59.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **very** obsolete. Rust 1.0 was released on 2015-05-15. This syntax was removed months before that. That means that your tutorial hasn't been updated in a long time; in fact, that file was last updated on 2014-01-28! Not a good sign.

The non-obsolete version of your code:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(10);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

1. The sigil `~` was replaced with specific data structures. In this case, [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html).
2. The format specifier `:d` no longer exists. Just use the [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) formatter `{}`.
3. There's no need to dereference the boxed number.

---

Instead of some "already obsolete" reference, use the official sources:

- [*The Rust Programming Language*, Second Edition](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/second-edition/index.html)
- [*The Rust Programming Language*, First Edition](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/first-edition/index.html)
- [Rust by Example](http://rustbyexample.com/)